# Units of a scalar field

Tags: si-units, absolute-units

Consider the Lagrangian density
$$\mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu a \partial^\mu a + \frac{m^2}{2} a^2.$$
I understand why $[a]=m$, i.e. $a$ has mass dimension one. What and **why** are the units of $a$ in the SI system?

If I were to know the units of $a$ in the SI, then knowing where and how many $c$'s and $\hbar$'s to place is easy to know, just match the units of each term. In this case, however, since I don't know the units of $a$ in the SI I can put any number of $c$'s and $\hbar$'s I want and give $a$ any units I want.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standardization of units for fields in particle physics.  The fields themselves are not physical observables, so there is no need to specify precise units for them.  As a consequence, they are normally given (like everything else) in units of power of energy, $[a]=$ GeV.  If you wanted to convert that to SI, you could, keeping it in units of energy, make the units of the field $a$ joules.  However, there would be nothing wrong with expressing them in other units that are related by powers of $c$ and $\hbar$; there is no physics in the specific choice.